# Once a Spellwrought Tattoo is on your skin, can it go back into needle form?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items

As the title says, I am wondering if Spellwrought Tattoos are able to go back to needle form if needed or if they will stay in your skin until consumed. In the text of tattoos that require attunement (basically every other magic tattoo) we get this text:

> If your attunement to the tattoo ends, the tattoo vanishes, and the needle reappears in your space.

But we have nothing like that on the Spellwrought Tattoo, so my guess is that once you get it on your skin there is no removing it until you consume it but I am still wondering if my guess is right. I, as a DM, would allow the removal of the tattoo to get it back into needle form, but I am part of a West March and recently this subject came up. Usually the other DMs ask me when in doubt about rules and such, but here I am not 100% sure and I can't seem to find any proper information on the subject anywhere, so here I am.

Comment: welcome! to clarify you are looking if the spellwrought tattoo can be returned to needle form based on rules as written, or are you looking for designer intent?

Comment: My favourite part of this question is that you, as a DM would allow it. Bravo.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### If the magic item description doesn’t say it, the magic item doesn’t do it.

As you have observed, the magic item description of a spellwrought tattoo contains no provision for returning the tattoo to needle form. So you can’t return it to needle form. There are no hidden or secret rules: everything you need to know about a magic item is contained in its description, as the rules for Using a Magic Item state:

> A magic item’s description explains how the item works.

Comment: I'm guessing this is because the *spellwrought tattoo* is a one-time use "consumable", whereas the other magic tattoos are more like non-consumable magic items that you have to attune to to use.